# How do I run WarCraft Frozen Throne (DOTA)?

Tags: wine

I am Using Linux for the very first time And i have one question. Dunno if it will be answered,but i hope so.. I have fujitsu ah 530 with intergrated video card(INTEL HD) so can i play my fav game on linux? And how to do it?

I installed it via Wine,but when i am starting the game with It,the game windows shows soooo poor,its unplayable,i can take i screenshot.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm experiencing:
[image: menus]

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to tweak wine.  I hear good things about playonlinux.  I haven't used either for gaming, but I've seen screenshots of warcraft on linux.

Comment: @DarKoza Please try to run the game with Unity2D (session: Ubuntu2D) instead of running with Unity3D, Unity3D uses OpenGL and might the reason why its conflicting with the game.

Comment: And i have one more question.I think this is the problem Of not displaying the game menu correctly.i went to command line by ctrl alt T and then whore lspci,and in the listing theres no such thing as VGI controller,seems that linux doesn't recognize my video card..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try forcing OpenGl mode in the game when you start it.

For a quick test you can just open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type this to start the game forcing OpenGl

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Warcraft\ III/Frozen\ Throne.exe -opengl
```

If it works, drop a comment so we can find a more permanent solution

Comment: Back in the day, I remember playing Warcraft III under either Cedega or Wine by using the `-opengl` flag for this reason - so this is quite likely to work.

Alternately it could be the other way around and you might need to force DirectX mode. Try both.

Comment: Amazing that the openGL mode is still as slow as it was back in the day. On a modern threadripper / 1080ti build, it still drops frames in opengl mode. Not sure if it's just a wine passthrough problem.

Answer (score 0):

As some stated in the comments, both [playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) and wine says that W3 TFT should run fine under linux ([playonlinux docs](http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/?script=19), [wine docs](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=897)).

I would try to install playonlinux ([here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)) first and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah at last,Thanks.I'm In my world Now -_- Bruno Pereira especially. U're Gr8 Guys. I'm damn happy right Now. Open gl Mode solved It totally, I think that Wc3 Now runs better Than On win 7 LoL :D